# make a calculation using values from two sheets in vba

Tags: excel, vba

Hi Im relatively new to vb so please excuse the bad code,

I want the code to calculate litres per hour used.

The userform asks the user to enter machine hours and the amount of fuel put into the machine that day(Litres required). It also asks the user to choose the machine number from a combobox and also the location from a combobox.

It then uses one worksheet to keep a record of all these entries (sheet1) and then updates the info in sheet2 to the latest info.

I need the code to take the current hours before the info is updated and take it away from the new current hours which will update the current hours. Litres required is then divided by the value from the previous calculation.

I then want this value put into the column Litres p/hr in sheet2.

Here is my current code:

```
   Private Sub btnupdate_Click()
       Dim row As Long    'next available row
       With Sheets("Sheet1")
          'get the next avialable row in Sheet1
           row = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1
          'put the text box values in this row
          .Range("A" & row).Value = cmbplantno.Value
          .Range("B" & row).Value = Txthours.Value
          .Range("C" & row).Value = txtfuel.Value
          .Range("D" & row).Value = caldate.Value
          .Range("E" & row).Value = cmblocation.Value
       End With

       Dim TheLastRow As Long
       TheLastRow = Sheet1.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row

       Rows(TheLastRow).Select
       Selection.Copy

       ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Activate      
       Columns("A:A").Select
       Selection.AutoFilter
       ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$63").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=cmbplantno


       Range("A2:A63") = cmbplantno.Value
       Range("E2:E63") = Txthours.Value
       Range("F2:F63") = caldate.Value
       Range("M2:M63") = cmblocation.Value
       Range("N2:N63") = txtfuel.Value

       Rows("63:63").Select
       Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
       ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$63").AutoFilter Field:=1

       cmbplantno.Value = ""
       Txthours.Value = ""
       txtfuel.Value = ""
       cmblocation.Value = "" 
   End Sub

Sub FillCtrlUnique(myRange As Range, myControl As Control)
    Dim Coll As New Collection
    Dim var As Variant
    Dim cell As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    For Each cell In myRange
        Coll.Add Item:=cell.Value, Key:=CStr(cell.Value)
    Next cell
    On Error GoTo 0

    With myControl
        .Clear
        For Each var In Coll
            .AddItem var
        Next var
    End With
    Set Coll = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim sRange As Range
    Set sRange = Range("E2:E62", Range("E63"))
    FillCtrlUnique sRange, Me.cmblocation

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        cmbplantno.List = .Range("A2:A62" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count)).Value
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    ThisWorkbook.Close savechanges:=True
    Application.Quit
End Sub
```

**Edit1:** Worksheet sample

[image]

Any help with this would be much appreciated. I will be pulling my hair out for weeks trying to figure this out by myself.

Comment: Your question is a bit broad. Can you trim it down to what is not working, what in your code doesn't quite do what you expect? What part of it gives you the hard time. For me or anyone to help you, we would have to recreate a sample and then re-write a whole set of codes for testing which will be too cumbersome.

Comment: @L42 basically i need some code to do a calculation for hours entered into the text box on the userform minus hours already present on the sheet. This value is then divided into the value entered in a textbox for fuel required on the userform and the result displayed in a worksheet

Comment: Can you somehow illustrate it like screen shot? You can upload it in any free hosting image site [i.imgur.com](http://imgur.com/) and I'll post it for you  in your question.

Comment: @L42 Ive uploaded images to imgur one of sheet1, one of sheet2 and one of the userform here is the imgur link http://imgur.com/9d5lJhh

Comment: By "take the current hours before the info is updated and take it away from the new current hours" do you mean you want 'CurrentHours = PrevCurrentHours - NewCurrentHours`?